# Can iOS UI automation execute app code?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, appium

I understand that I can query elements and invoke user commands on them, such as tap or swipe. Can I call actual code though? For example if I have a `foo` method on the current view controller or a static `Bar` method in a utility class, can I call them during my test? Something like:

1. Locate button and tap it
2. Call some method
3. query field of some text box

If the answer is yes, can I do it in Appium as well?

Comment: Why not just make the button call the code?

Comment: Perhaps this is code that I only want to run during testing. For example delete some value from some list to emulate servers-side changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute any code from UI Automation, but you can perform UI events and using them you can execute code.